# Добавить в List<Object> экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется один экземпляр Object, который каждый раз меняет свои значения свойств, при этом, после изменения свойства он добавляется в List через метод Add(Object). Теперь, при сбросе свойств экземпляра они сбрасываются в List. Как можно передать в List не ссылку экземпляра, а сам экземпляр?

Comment: Классы в C# передаются по ссылке. Делайте копию экземпляра и передавайте, либо поменяйте `class` на `struct`, тогда передаваться будет всегда по значению.

Comment: для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, данные добавляются в List, Затем лист привязывается к ItemSource таблицы DataGrid

Comment: Может это всё таки должны быть разные экземпляры?

Comment: @yolosora, я тоже думаю каждый раз передавать новый экземпляр с новыми данными, а не менять один и тот же..

Comment: @trollingchar, копировать экземпляр лучше всего реализуя интерфейс ICloneable? или есть варианты проще?

Comment: @Maks а покажите ваш класс. Может вообще будет лучше объявить его `struct`, если в нем мало данных.

Comment: @trollingchar, исправил немного свой код, всё-таки сделал так, чтобы каждый раз создавался новый экземпляр, всё работает отлично

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Clone` в помощь. А чтобы он был, `object : IClonable`, и реализуйте его.

Comment: Добавление интерфейса ничего не делает само по себе. Этот метод нужно _реализовать_ самостоятельно. И вообще, даже в документации его не рекомендуют выставлять наружу.